# Angular filter for gender using select dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a database that need to be filtered by gender. Everything is working fine.

But when i filter by gender, as female is part of male, female is also showing up.
If i pick female, then male is hiding off.

[Here is my jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/kg2kscnw/11/)

```
<select name="" id="" ng-model="test.filterByGender">
<option value="">By Gender</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
  <option value="male">Male</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it works fine when I changed the code to `<option value="malex">Male</option>` i don' get the point why `male` exactly doesn't work and `malex` works.. try it .. (don't forget to change the value in the JSONs docs )

Comment: @Selem: it is because that "Female" contains "male", so it also counts as a match. To make this works, we somehow have to tell angular to do an exact match, something like <tr ng-repeat="subject in test.subjects | filter:test.filterByState | filter:{gender:(test.filterByGender || undefined)}:true | filter:test.filterByAge">

Comment: weird and clever behavior :) Thanks @HoàngLong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be working.

https://jsfiddle.net/kg2kscnw/14/

```
<tr ng-repeat="subject in test.subjects | filter:test.filterByState | filter:(!!test.filterByGender || undefined) && test.filterByGender:true | filter:test.filterByAge">
    <td>{{subject.name}}</td>
    <td>{{subject.gender}}</td>
    <td>{{subject.age}}</td>
 </tr>
```

If you set the comparator to true, it sets up a strict comparison of actual and expected, so it can see that 'male' is not the same as 'female'.  But then it doesn't recognise the empty value of the 'By gender' field.  In order to get around this, you can tell the filter to only be applied if the value is not empty or undefined.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it seems that your code works ok, though I can't understand the double (!). Could you please elaborate a little bit?

Comment: From what I understand, it's just a double 'not' operator.  It's basically applying the filter if the value is not ( the first !) empty ( the second !) or undefined.  Incidentally, it seems to be working when you remove both of the 'not' operators, too, so maybe it's just there to cause confusion ;)

Answer (score 2):

[From doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

> Selects a subset of items from `array` and returns it as a new array.

It works like `String.Contains` method. So when you select `male` from drop-down, it shows all data because `female` also contains `male` sub-string.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
 vm = this;
  
  vm.subjects = [
  
       {
            name : "Alpha",
            location:"TN",
            age : "25",
            gender:"female"
            },
             {
            name : "Beta",
            location:"TN",
            age : "44",
            gender:"male"
            },
             {
            name : "Gamma",
            location:"KE",
            age : "20",
            gender:"female"
            },
             {
            name : "Theta",
            location:"AN",
            age : "22",
            gender:"female"
            },
  
  
  ];
  
  angular.forEach( vm.subjects, function(subject){  
   if(parseInt(subject.age) <= 25){
     subject.ageFilterCriteria = '<25'
    }
    else{
    subject.ageFilterCriteria = '>25'
    }
  
  })
  console.log(vm.subjects);
  vm.filterByAge = '';
  vm.filterByState='';
  vm.filterByGender='';
  
  vm.setFlag = function(value){
     if(value)
       vm.flag = true;
    else
       vm.flag = false;
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl as test">
<select name="" id="" ng-model="test.filterByState">
<option value="">Select a state</option>
  <option value="TN">TamilNadu</option>
  <option value="KE">Kerala</option>
  <option value="AN">Andra Pradesh</option>
</select>
<select name="" id="" ng-model="test.filterByGender" ng-change="test.setFlag(test.filterByGender)">
<option value="">By Gender</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
  <option value="male">Male</option>
</select>
<select name="" id="" ng-model="test.filterByAge">
<option value="">Select All</option>
  <option value="<25">Less Than 25</option>
  <option value=">25">Greater Than 25</option>
</select>
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="subject in test.subjects |filter:{location:test.filterByState,ageFilterCriteria:test.filterByAge}| filter:{gender:test.filterByGender}:test.flag">
    <td>{{subject.name}}</td>
    <td>{{subject.gender}}</td>
    <td>{{subject.age}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>


</div>
```

try this:

```
  <select name="" id="" ng-model="test.filterByGender" ng-change="test.flag =true">
   <option value="">By Gender</option>
   <option value="female">Female</option>
   <option value="male">Male</option>
  </select>


   <tr ng-repeat="subject in test.subjects |filter:{location:test.filterByState,ageFilterCriteria:test.filterByAge}|
                                            filter:{gender:test.filterByGender}:test.flag">
```

Comment: Yes. But at initial state not all datas are populated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Filter give the result on the basis of matching items.So female rows are showing when you select male from drop-down because "female" word contains the "male" word .